# Not able to connect Mysql server from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I have installed `PHP 7.1` and `MYSQL 5.5` in IIS server from web platform installer. We have installed MySQL 5.6 with port 3307 manually by downloading since Mysql 5.5 not supporting some functionality.

In same windows system, we have wamp with `Mysql 5.7` with port `3306`. We have recently moved from WAMP to IIS. But we have kept WAMP for backup.

We have faced some problem while connecting to 3307 due to the port open issue. So we changed IIS `MySQL 5.6` port to `3306`. From command-line, we are able to access this MySQL server.

But from PHP, we are not able to connect this MySQL using a simple MySQL script.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","abc*123$","abc_uat_qa",'3306');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Do we need to change mysql path or some setting in `php.ini` or `mysql` settings?

**Edit:**

How can we check MySQL version from PHP script without connecting MYSQL server?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: have you verify mysql password or password is blank?

Comment: @NigelRen : We have changed Mysql 5.6 port to 3306. So now it is listening on port 3306. Tested from command-line.

Comment: @PankajMakwana: Same password is used to connect from command line>mysql -u root -p --port 3306

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can check php version and mysql version from this functions

```
<?php 
    // get php version
    echo phpversion().'<br/>';
    //get mysql version
    echo mysql_get_server_info();
?>
```

you can change mysql port from `php.ini` in `line 1268`

```
mysql.default_port=3306
```

change port from this line

Comment: mysql_get_server_info(); will not give MySQL version without connecting MySQL. I have already set the port to 3306.

Comment: to get mysql version without connection use this:     `print mysql_get_client_info();` and will print mysql version like this `mysqlnd 5.0.11`